# Rails SQL query in controller method

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, solr

I want to retrieve brand name depending on brand_id which is mentioned in the another table products. My brand ids are stored as an array in 'brandids'. Here is my controller code.

```
def index
    catids = Array.new
    brandids = Array.new
    @products = nil
    if(!(params[:catid].nil?) && params[:catid].to_s.downcase != "all")
        catids = arrayConvertion(params[:catid])
    end

    if(!(params[:brandid].nil?) && params[:brandid].to_s.downcase != "all")
        brandids = arrayConvertion(params[:brandid])
    end

    if(catids.length == 0 && brandids.length == 0)
        @products = Product.solr_search do
        paginate :page => params[:page], :per_page => 3
    end

    @brands={}
    @products.each do |p|
        brand = p.BrandsTest.first(p.brands_test_id)
        @brands[p.id] = BrandsTest.name
    end
end
```

and the view for this controller is:

```
<% @products.results.each do |p| %>
       <%= image_tag("Images/#{p.id}.jpeg",:alt => p.name) %>
       <p> Name: </p> 
       <%= p.name %>
       <p> Price: </p>
       <%= p.price %>
       <p> Discount: </p>
       <%= p.discount %>
       <p> Brand Name: </p>
       <%= @brands[p.id] %>
<% end %>
```

Product Model code is:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :brands_test
  belongs_to :categories_test
  attr_accessible :id, :name

  searchable do
    integer :id
    text :name
    integer  :brands_test_id
    integer :categories_test_id
  end
end
```

What query should I need to add and where I have to add?
Please help me with this.

Comment: I tried with this.    `@products = Product.solr_search do 
                       @brands = BrandsTest.solr_search do
                         with :name, brandids[0..brandids.length]
                         paginate :page=>params[:page], :per_page=>3
                       end
                     end`. And changed viewfile as                  `<% @products.results.each do |p| %>
<% @brands.results.each do |b| %>
  <p> Brand name: </p>
     <%= b.name %>`
But I'm getting following error.  No field configured for BrandsTest with name 'name'

Answer (score 0):

```
@products = Product.solr_search do
    with :brands_test_id, brandids[0..brandids.length]
    paginate :page=>params[:page], :per_page=>3
end
@brands={}
@products.each do |p|
brand=Brand.find_by_id(p.brand_id)
@brands[p.id]=brand.name
end
```

views:

```
<% @products.results.each do |p| %>
    #other code
   <p> Brand: </p>
   <%= @brands[p.id]   
<% end %>
```

I don't sure if I understood what are you trying to do.

Comment: I'm getting this error. Sunspot::UnrecognizedFieldError in ProductsController#index

No field configured for Product with name 'name'.                 The thing is brand name is not present in products table. So i need to extract brand name from brands table using brand_id in products table. That's why I'm getting that error i think. @Joe

Comment: Do you mean getting this error with my code? Actually my code is getting brand name directly from Brand table, and than just passes is to hash with the key of product id, so that you can easily get value in products view.

Comment: Brand belongs to Product? Through has_one? Try brand = p.brand

Comment: Can you please show code of Models and product create method?

Comment: Yeah brands to products has one to many relationship. I tried p.brands.first also but getting the same error.Brands has 2 columns id and name. Products table has 5 columns. that is id,name,brands_test_id,discount and price. Currently I'm displaying product name,discount,price using brands_test_id. Now,I want to display brand name using that brands_test_id. Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: can you please post as 'answer your question', it may help another users and also I want to know what was the problem)

Answer (score 0):

I did some modification according my app with the answer that you gave.Here is the controller part.

```
if(catids.length == 0 && brandids.length == 0)
    @products = Product.solr_search do
        paginate :page=>params[:page], :per_page=>3
    end
    @brands={}
    @products.results.each do |p|
        brand=BrandsTest.find_by_id(p.brands_test_id)
        @brands[p.id]=brand.name
    end
end
```

Here is view part:

```
<% @products.results.each do |p| %>
    <%= image_tag("Images/#{p.id}.jpeg",:alt => p.name) %>
<p> Name: </p> 
<%= p.name %>
<p> Price: </p>
<%= p.price %>
<p> Discount: </p>
<%= p.discount %>
    <p> Brand Name: </p>
    <%= @brands[p.id]%>
<% end %>
```